# Office365 Forwarded Email Preference History

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange, history, forwarding

Is it possible to see the history of preference changes in the Exchange Admin Center? I have a shared mailbox that was forwarding emails to an internal email address but the original forwarded address was changed to someone else. Since the internal email address turns into, what I would assume to be a special ID, I was not able to immediate see the email that the shared mailbox was forwarding messages to. So my question is if there's a way to check the history of what email addresses that the share mailbox used to forward the emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a bit more searching of the Exchange Admin Center, found out I can do a message trace and see who the previous forwarded email was. Under "**Admin Centers**", I clicked "**Security**", from there I clicked "**Exchange message trace**" and from there I was able to search for the previous emails and discover which email address the messages were being forwarded to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Message Trace in EAC to find out what happened to an email.

More details, you can refer to this MS document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/monitoring/trace-an-email-message/run-a-message-trace-and-view-results.